# Get last element in unbounded xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an unbounded XML which changed depending on the Request URL

Assume the URL : 
 localhost/Years

```
<Response>
  <Record>
    <Years>1425</Years>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Years>233</Years>
  </Record>
</Response>
```

Assume the URL: 

 localhost/Names

```
<Response>
  <Record>
    <Names>John</Names>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Names>Bisho</Names>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Names>Curry</Names>
  </Record>
</Response>
```

Assume URL : loaclhost/laptop&mobiles

```
<Response>
  <Record>
    <laptop>dell</laptop>
    <mobiles>samsung</mobiles>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <laptop>apple</laptop>
    <mobiles>lenovo</mobiles>
  </Record>
</Response>
```

Need a XSL Script to get the Last value in the response xml Like 233 for years or Curry for names and so on depending on the URL.

Comment: How would the XSLT know the URL? Can you pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Please post the expected result **as code**. And answer the clarifying question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Response">
    <xsl:for-each select="Record[last()]/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
233
```

for your first example,

```
Curry
```

for your second example, and:

```
apple
lenovo
```

for your last example.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `last()` function to get the last element and `text()` to get its value. If you want it to work for both xPaths (Years and Names), use `*`.

The final xPath is as follows: `/Response/Record[last()]/*/text()`.